# How to create rating system using for loop in php yii2

Tags: php, for-loop, yii2, rating, rating-system

I am working a project where i need rating system. I use kartik widget to rate but now i need some code to show rates. total stars 5 if a user get 4 star then 4 stars will be filled and one star will be empty. I did it on custom writing and I need some efficient code.

```
    public static function rate($rate)
{
    if (!is_null($rate)) {

     if ($rate == 0){
       echo "<i class='fa fa-star-o'></i>";
       echo "<i class='fa fa-star-o'></i>";
       echo "<i class='fa fa-star-o'></i>";
       echo "<i class='fa fa-star-o'></i>";
       echo "<i class='fa fa-star-o'></i>";
     }
     if ($rate >= 1 && $rate < 1.5){
      echo "<i class='fa fa-star'></i>";
       echo "<i class='fa fa-star-o'></i>";
       echo "<i class='fa fa-star-o'></i>";
       echo "<i class='fa fa-star-o'></i>";
       echo "<i class='fa fa-star-o'></i>";
     }
     if ($rate >= 1.5 && $rate < 2){
       echo "<i class='fa fa-star'></i>";
       echo "<i class='fa fa-star-half-o'></i>";
       echo "<i class='fa fa-star-o'></i>";
       echo "<i class='fa fa-star-o'></i>";
       echo "<i class='fa fa-star-o'></i>";
     }
     if ($rate >= 2 && $rate < 2.5){
       echo "<i class='fa fa-star'></i>";
       echo "<i class='fa fa-star'></i>";
       echo "<i class='fa fa-star-o'></i>";
       echo "<i class='fa fa-star-o'></i>";
       echo "<i class='fa fa-star-o'></i>";
     }
     if ($rate >= 2.5 && $rate < 3){
       echo "<i class='fa fa-star'></i>";
       echo "<i class='fa fa-star'></i>";
       echo "<i class='fa fa-star-half-o'></i>";
       echo "<i class='fa fa-star-o'></i>";
       echo "<i class='fa fa-star-o'></i>";
     }
     if ($rate >= 3 && $rate < 3.5){
       echo "<i class='fa fa-star'></i>";
       echo "<i class='fa fa-star'></i>";
       echo "<i class='fa fa-star'></i>";
       echo "<i class='fa fa-star-o'></i>";
       echo "<i class='fa fa-star-o'></i>";
     }
     if ($rate >= 3.5 && $rate < 4){
       echo "<i class='fa fa-star'></i>";
       echo "<i class='fa fa-star'></i>";
       echo "<i class='fa fa-star'></i>";
       echo "<i class='fa fa-star-half-o'></i>";
       echo "<i class='fa fa-star-o'></i>";
     }
     if ($rate >= 4 && $rate < 4.5){
       echo "<i class='fa fa-star'></i>";
       echo "<i class='fa fa-star'></i>";
       echo "<i class='fa fa-star'></i>";
       echo "<i class='fa fa-star'></i>";
       echo "<i class='fa fa-star-o'></i>";
     }
     if ($rate >= 4.5 && $rate < 5){
       echo "<i class='fa fa-star'></i>";
       echo "<i class='fa fa-star'></i>";
       echo "<i class='fa fa-star'></i>";
       echo "<i class='fa fa-star'></i>";
       echo "<i class='fa fa-star-half-o'></i>";
     }
     if ($rate >= 5){
       echo "<i class='fa fa-star'></i>";
       echo "<i class='fa fa-star'></i>";
       echo "<i class='fa fa-star'></i>";
       echo "<i class='fa fa-star'></i>";
       echo "<i class='fa fa-star'></i>";
     }
}
else
{
  echo "<i style='color: red'>Not Yet rated</i>";
}
}
```

How can i do this same work using loop

Comment: a loop of what  ?   .. you want loop over a list of user and show the related rate?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
public static function rate($rate)
{
    if (!is_null($rate)) {        
        $rate_int = $rate/0.5;
        for($i=1; $i<=floor($rate); $i++){
            echo "<i class='fa fa-star'></i>";
        }  

        if(($rate_int % 2) == 0) {
            for($i=1; $i<=5-$rate; $i++) {
                echo "<i class='fa fa-star-o'></i>";
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo "<i class='fa fa-star-half-o'></i>";
            for($i=1; $i<=5-($rate+1); $i++){
                echo "<i class='fa fa-star-o'></i>";
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<i style='color: red'>Not Yet rated</i>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have a collection of users model names $userModels and in this model you have a field name $rate  for rate 
you could invoke your static function

```
  foreach( $userModels as $key => $value){
      YourClass::rate($value->rate);

  }
```